# How to display the contents of several records into one?

Tags: django, django-admin

how to display the contents of several records into one ???

I have to do something like that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUBKK.png)

Comment: Do you want to display several fields (combination of) in a single field? Is that what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Yes i want to display several fields (combination of) in a single field.

Comment: can you say where came the records from? or give us an example?

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
from django.db import models


class Item(models.Model):
    """Item model."""

    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    url = models.TextField(
        null=False,
        blank=False
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(
        default=False
    )

    class Meta(object):
        """Meta options."""

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .models import Item

@admin.register(Item)
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Item admin."""

    list_display = (
        'id',
        'title',
        'url',
        'active',
        'combined',
    )

    def combined(self, obj):
        """Combined data.

        :return:
        """
        return format_html(
            '''
            {}<br/>
            {}<br/>
            {}
            ''',
            obj.title,
            obj.url,
            obj.active
        )

    combined.short_description = _("Combined data")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help

Comment: How to display  combined data in template ?

Comment: {{ obj.title }}<br/>{{ obj.url }}<br/>{{ obj.active }}